# Inserting custom time, Scanner and Valuer implemented — but still errs

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have a custom time format that is the result of some custom unmarshalling:

```
type customTime struct {
    time.Time
}
```

I have implemented the `Scanner` and `Valuer` interface on this `customTime` like so:

```
func (ct *customTime) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    ct.Time = value.(time.Time)
    return nil
}

func (ct *customTime) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return ct.Time, nil
}
```

But it still errs when I try to do the insert:

> sql: converting Exec argument $3 type: unsupported type main.customTime, a struct

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the solution, `Scanner` and `Valuer` should be implemented on the actual value and not a pointer to the `customTime`

```
func (ct customTime) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    ct.Time = value.(time.Time)
    return nil
}

func (ct customTime) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return ct.Time, nil
}
```